# If single-threaded and non-blocking are defining features of JavaScript, why are these terms absent from the specification?

Tags: javascript, specifications, javascript-engine, language-specifications

JavaScript is turning out to be a complex ecosystem. Recently I've been reading more from the official language specification and learning a little bit more about browser implementations.

Can someone help me understand where non-blocking and single-threaded are specified? Is there some other specification I should be looking at?

I tried here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Comment: @DanD. So that's a browser thing? How do the vendors coordinate? They must have a standard of their own. Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you expect to find *non-blocking* discussed in an environment that is single-threaded? Asynchronous operations (the non-blocking stuff) isn't handled by the JS runtime, it's handled by the browser's Web API processor. The single-threaded-ness is described in the way that the spec. talks about execution contexts.